# Dont display the button if any value exist in quantity

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Goal:
The button named "btnReturn" should not be displayed if the value of the quantity is 0 and minus.

Problem:
Have considered alot and I can't find a solution to make the button not to be invisible.
It can be a XAML code or C#.

Please remember that you have lots of product to be displayed and I also used datacontext to sync between XAML and list.

```
private void UpdateGUI(int pSaleId)
{
    lstRepurchase.DataContext = _myManagerProduct_SaleAndProductQuantity.DisplaySoldProductInTheRepurchaseListView(pSaleId);
}
```

```
<ListView  Canvas.Left="8" Canvas.Top="49.494" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="236.78,17.48,8,44.707" Name="lstRepurchase">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Article Number" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=_articleNumber}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left" />                                  
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=_name}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=_quantity}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left" />                                            
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Name="btnReturn" MinHeight="20" MinWidth="50" Content="Delete" Click="btnReturn_Click" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: No, it's my personal WPF project to improve my skills in computer programming.

Comment: "Please remember that you have lots of product to be displayed..." made it sound like an assignment a little, but it's cool if it's yours; it would OK if it's homework too, just making sure it's properly labeled.

Comment: Gawd, it's *"XAML"*, not *"xamel"*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a converter for Int32 to Visability.  Now the syntax for passing the count to the convert could need to bind to the ItemSource for count.

```
    [ValueConversion(typeof(Int32), typeof(Visibility))]
    public class IntVisabilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Int32 inCount = (Int32)value;
            if (inCount > 0) return Visibility.Visible;
            else return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
    <xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yourNameSpace"        
    <local:VisabilityConverter x:Key="visabilityConverter"/>
    Visibility="{Binding Path=Count, Converter={StaticResource visabilityConverter}
```

You will need to read up for where those lines go but they are all on the XAML.

Comment: 1) Consider renaming of "Visability" to "Visibility".  2) throw exception in COnvertBack if you won't implement it

Comment: I tried testing your solution and I tried using other xaml code but no effect would be happening. What suggested or created xaml would you use?

Comment: Another question.. this code "    [ValueConversion(typeof(Int32), typeof(Visibility))] what value can this code help me?
"

Comment: I did misspell visibility. Return true is A recommended design practice - this is bound oneway so why take the hit of throwing an error.  I posted the syntax for how to attach to the converter.  The value is to convert an Int32 to Visibility.  MSDN can help you with how to implement a converter.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind the Visibility property to the _quantity property and use a converter which takes in the quantity and returns a visibility.

Here is some information regarding converters:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/OppositeBoolConverter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Boolean-to-Visibility Converter, see an example of custom and flexible converter [here - BooleanToVisibilityConverter by Kent Boogaart](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2011/02/booleantovisibilityconverter.html).
Or use built-in [BooleanToVisibilityConverter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx)

1) Define boolean property like

```cs
public bool IsQuantityGreaterThenZero
{
  get
  {  
      return this.quantity > 0;
  }
}
```

2) Update buttond definition in XAML to use binding with converter in place:

```xml
<Button Visibility="{Binding IsQuantityGreaterThenZero,
        Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: I tried making a dummy of the whole concept of Boolean-to-Visibiity Converter in my application and I get a error message in the xaml code "<local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="whatever" IsReversed="true" UseHidden="true"/>", "The type 'local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter' was not found. vierfy that you are not missing an assenbly reference and that all referenced assembles have been built."

Comment: In which namespace you placed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter?

Comment: In XAML see which namespace is referenced by alias "local", in this namespace should be converter class.I would suggest to introduce new alias converters and place all converters in this namespace

Comment: There is one thing I dont understand. How are you enable to make the variable "quantity"  to gain the value from the listview? If I understand you have to make some kind of calculation in the method "Convert" that maek the variable quantity to gain a value?

Comment: The problem statement calls for quantity (not bool) to visibility converter.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the button to change Visibility when 'quantity' is zero or less.
Try messing around with the button's visible or visibility property.
This C# code will make a Windows Form button invisible:

```
if(quantity <=0)
    btnReturn.Visibile = false;
```

Comment: It is visibility and and it is not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. The Boolean to Visibility converter is native in WPF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx